# how to query a firestore collection from latest to the oldest when using pagination?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm querying a firestore collection and uses `flutterfire's` [FirestoreQueryBuilder](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/ui/firestore/) for pagination and it should query 10 documents per page at a time.

Here is my firestore collection :

[image]

What I need is to query from the latest data to the oldest
The latest is at the bottom and the oldest is at the top.

The problem is querying firestore collection always starts from the top.
even though you will order the query by date like so: `query.where(something).orderBy('date', descending: true)`.
What this does is grab the first 10 documents from the top then order them by date which is not what i want.

So the question is how can we query firestore collection that starts from the bottom up so that i could get the first latest 10 documents?

Or another thing i'm thinking is can we reverse the order of firestore collection?
That if we add a document, it should append to the top not push to the bottom? is this possible?

Here is my code for querying firestore collection:

```html
  Query<T> collectionQuery<T>({
    required String path,
    required T Function(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot,
            SnapshotOptions? options)
        fromMap,
    required Map<String, Object?> Function(T, SetOptions? options) toMap,
    Query<T> Function(Query<T>? query)? queryBuilder,
  }) {
    Query<T> query = firestore
        .collection(path)
        .withConverter<T>(fromFirestore: fromMap, toFirestore: toMap);
    if (queryBuilder != null) {
      return query = queryBuilder(query);
    } else {
      return query;
    }
  }
```

And here is how i use FirestoreQueryBuilder to display the collection:

```html
  return FirestoreQueryBuilder<T>(
      pageSize: pageSize,
      query: query,
      builder: (context, snapshot, ___) {
        if (snapshot.isFetching) {
          return loading ?? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
              snapshot.error.toString(),
              style: Styles.k16Bold,
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
          return emptyWidget ??
              const Center(
                  child: Text(
                'No item found',
                style: Styles.k18Grey,
              ));
        }
        return ListView.separated(
          padding: padding ?? const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          controller: listController,
          reverse: reverListView,
          itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
          separatorBuilder: (_, __) => separator,
          itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
            if (snapshot.hasMore && index + 1 == snapshot.docs.length) {
              // Tell FirestoreQueryBuilder to try to obtain more items.
              // It is safe to call this function from within the build method.
              if (connection) {
                snapshot.fetchMore();
              }
            }

            final list =
                reverseItems ? snapshot.docs.reversed.toList() : snapshot.docs;
            print('list: ${list.length}');

            if (sort != null) {
              final item = list[index].data();
              list.sort(sort);

              return itemBuilder(item, index);
            } else {
              final item = list[index].data();
              return itemBuilder(item, index);
            }
          }),
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like

```
final query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
                  .orderBy("timestamp")
                  .limit(10);
```

This will give you the result where the latest data will be at the bottom and the oldest will at the top.

Comment: could you share some example of how to use the `.startAt()` since it accepts a parameter of `List<Object?>` and i cant find an example how to use it in flutter. the example in the doc is in other languages.

Comment: @john Yes it is documented in FlutterFire [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#start--end-cursors)

Comment: this doesn't help. this only specifies where the query should start. not the order. And the `orderBy()` method only orders the first 10 documents that are fetched. The main question is how to order all the collection then paginate it and get 10 docs per page.

Comment: @john Hi I have recreated your problem and as you said you want to get the result where the latest data will be at the bottom and the oldest will be at the top. I have updated the code for that.

Comment: you answer doesnt work. I think there is no way you can sort all the collections without querying them. your code. doesn't have any change at all. what your code is doing is only to sort the 10 documents not the whole collection.